# How do I go about creating an engine for Flash that I can import and use in a game?

Tags: flash, adobe, game-engine

I have been making sprites for an animation, however, I want to make a simple platformer almost like a Mario clone, but don't know how to code one. Should I use DreamWeaver or FlashBuilder? Any other tips or advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can start pretty easily using Flash Develop from: http://www.flashdevelop.org/
With Flash Develop, you can also start with an 'engine' or framework to make coding the game easier like FlashPunk (http://useflashpunk.net/) or Flixel (http://flixel.org/)